# Regular expression is not working and timing out

Tags: c#, regex

Something maybe wrong with my regular expression (maybe it's looping too much)
I think it causes the MVC (C#) web app to timeout as well...

The regEx is:

```
public const string UrlPartPost = @"^([0-9a-zA-Z-/]*){1,256}$";
```

I use it like this:

```
Regex.Match(urlPart3, RegExKeys.UrlPartPost, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

I added a live test - which is also timing out: 
https://regex101.com/r/vZ0lN5/1

this is fine: test1-test2-test3-test4-test5

this times out: test1-test2-test3-test4-test_5

**How can I fix it so it does not time out?**

**UPDATE:** 
What is the "*" supposed to do exactly?

Comment: just `[\da-zA-Z-/]+` or `[0-9a-zA-Z-/]{1,256}`

Comment: I forgot why I had the asterisk in there... not sure what it does, I do need to make sure the string is between 1 and 256 in length...

Comment: Well, I don't see your test string is timing out but not succeeding based on pattern. see https://regex101.com/r/vZ0lN5/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` means match 0+ times, as many as possible.

Your regex is catastrophically backtracking.

Your regex doesn't really make sense, you might want to describe what you're trying to match. You also don't need `A-Z` and `a-z` if you are using the case insensitive modifier.

If you want to ensure you have a string with 1-256 of the characters specified, try this: `^([-0-9a-z/]){1,256}$`

Comment: I think I need to get some sleep, when I wake up I would love to know why I did put that asterisk in there (that was a while ago), it seems to work without it... I think I was trying to allow forward slashes...